# Why can I combine `Plug` and `set` in vimrc, but cannot `nnoremap`?

Tags: vim, neovim

I can combine two lines like below,

```
autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot' | Plug 'ap/vim-css-color'
set splitright splitbelow
```

but cannot with nnoremap like below.

```
nnoremap <Up> gk | nnoremap <Down> gj
```

Why this happens, and how could I resolve?

Comment: Command `nnoremap <Up> gk | nnoremap <Down> gj` kind of works, in that it creates a mapping for both `<Up>` and `<Down>`... It does have one undesirable side effect, that the mapping for `<Up>` has a trailing space. (But the same would be true if the line ends with trailing spaces too...)

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I understand why it behaves wrong. Thanks! @filbranden

Answer (score 0):

solved.

need to trim white space before |.